# Getting apostrophe prepended after batch update on every row updated

Tags: php, google-sheets

```
$data = [];
array_push(
  $data,
  new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange([
      'range' => $year.'!'. self::GOOGLECOL_PRICE_COLUMN . $e['rowIndex'],
      'values' =>  [[number_format((double) $data['price'], 0, '.', ' ')]]
  ])
);
array_push(
  $data,
  new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange([
      'range' => $year.'!'. self::GOOGLECOL_PRICETWO_COLUMN. $e['rowIndex'],
      'values' =>  [[number_format((double) $data['price_two'], 0, '.', ' ')]]
  ])
);
array_push(
  $data,
  new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange([
      'range' => $year.'!'. self::GOOGLECOL_PRICETHREE_COLUMN . $e['rowIndex'],
      'values' =>  [[number_format((double) $price, 0, '.', ' ')]]
  ])
);
$body = new Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateValuesRequest([
    "valueInputOption" => "RAW",
    "data" => $data
]);

$this->_service->spreadsheets_values->batchUpdate($this->_sheetId, $body);
```

I do this and I get the results I want except that I get these `'` characters prepended, is there a reason for this?

example: `'1231 '0 '0`

I also did a console log on body and got:

```
{"includeValuesInResponse":null,"responseDateTimeRenderOption":null,"responseValueRenderOption":null,"valueInputOption":"RAW","data":[{"majorDimension":null,"range":"2022!D28","values":[["1231"]]},{"majorDimension":null,"range":"2022!F28","values":[["0"]]},{"majorDimension":null,"range":"2022!G28","values":[["0"]]}]}
```

So it's not even coming from my code, but it's coming from the API itself.

Comment: What is `double` and where does its value come from?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo that's just a type cast. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php